# Supervised and unsupervised learning graphic in tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I would like to represent these two plots using `tikzpicture`. I don't need them joined together as below but I would like to have something similar.

[image]

I can generate a scatter plot as below:

[image]

Where I have two unique / distinct clusters. I would like to draw the linearly separable line as in the supervised learning example, whilst also drawing the clusters in the unsupervised learning example.

Additionally, having the colors/larger points would be great.

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
axis lines = left,
xlabel = x,
ylabel = y,
]
\addplot[only marks] table [%
x = x, 
y = y, 
col sep = comma]{
    x, y
    %cluster 1
    2, 3
    3, 5
    4, 5
    3, 8
    5, 9
    3, 2
    5, 6
    6, 6
    7, 9
    10, 4
    11, 5
    9, 4
    %cluser 2
    
    20, 10
    21, 12
    24, 12
    25, 13
    27, 14
    22, 13
    23, 15
    25, 10
    15, 14
 };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `scatter/classes` to format the points from the two clusters differently,  but it's easier to just split it in two `\addplot`s. To set the formatting, use e.g. `\addplot [blue, only marks, mark=*, mark size=5] ...`, which are mostly self-explanatory I guess.

For the line and circles it's almost just a case of using normal TikZ commands. Just note that by default, if you do `\draw (x,y) ..` inside an `axis` environment, `x` and `y` are not in the coordinate system of the `axis`. *Unless* you either a) use `(axis cs:x,y)`, or b) add `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}` (or a higher version number), in which case `axis cs` becomes the default.

Note further that a `circle[radius=2]` inside an `axis` requires `compat=1.11` (I think), but the radius is again in axis coordinates, so in this case it would become an ellipse. What you could do instead is define a coordinate inside the `axis`, and draw the circle outside of it. Both are demonstrated in the code below.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11} % <-- added
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
axis lines = left,
xlabel = $x$,
ylabel = $y$,
clip mode=individual % so things drawn by \draw and similar are not cut off
]
\addplot [blue, only marks, mark=*, mark size=5] table [%
x = x, 
y = y, 
col sep = comma]{
    x, y
    %cluster 1
    2, 3
    3, 5
    4, 5
    3, 8
    5, 9
    3, 2
    5, 6
    6, 6
    7, 9
    10, 4
    11, 5
    9, 4
    };
    
\addplot+[red, only marks, mark=*, mark size=5] table [%
x = x, 
y = y, 
col sep = comma]{
    x, y
    20, 10
    21, 12
    24, 12
    25, 13
    27, 14
    22, 13
    23, 15
    25, 10
    15, 14
 };
 
 % to be able to use axis coordinates with \draw directly you need
 % \pgfplotsset{compat=1.11} or a higher version
 % if that is not present, use (axis cs:4,14) instead of (4,14),
 % to specify that the values should be interpreted as axis coordinates
 \draw [dashed] (4,14) -- (25,2);
 
 % save a coordinate for use later
 \coordinate (c2) at (23,12);
 
 % the blue circle is drawn inside the axis environment, and in axis coordinates
 % hence it becomes an ellipse
 \draw [blue, dashed] (6,6) circle[radius=5]; 

\end{axis}

% the red circle is drawn outside the axis, so actually looks like a circle,
% but the radius has no relation to the axis coordinates
\draw [red, dashed] (c2) circle[radius=2cm];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Two axes

There are multiple methods for getting two plots next to each other. You could add two `tikzpicture`s one right after the other, or you could have two `axis` environments in the same `tikzpicture` and position the second one with `\begin{axis}[at={(x,y)},...`. Personally I like the `groupplot` environment from the `groupplots` library, which is for making grids of axes.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[
group style={
  group size=2 by 1,
  horizontal sep=1.5cm
  },
axis lines = left,
xlabel = $x$,
ylabel = $y$,
width=5cm, % <-- set size of axes
clip mode=individual, % to avoid \draws being cut off
title style={yshift=1mm, font=\bfseries\sffamily}
]

\nextgroupplot[title=Supervised learning]
\addplot [blue, only marks, mark=*, mark size=3] table [%
x = x, 
y = y, 
col sep = comma]{
    x, y
    %cluster 1
    2, 3
    3, 5
    4, 5
    3, 8
    5, 9
    3, 2
    5, 6
    6, 6
    7, 9
    10, 4
    11, 5
    9, 4
    };
    
\addplot+[red, only marks, mark=*, mark size=3] table [%
x = x, 
y = y, 
col sep = comma]{
    x, y
    20, 10
    21, 12
    24, 12
    25, 13
    27, 14
    22, 13
    23, 15
    25, 10
    15, 14
 };
 
 % to be able to use axis coordinates with \draw directly you need
 % \pgfplotsset{compat=1.11} or a higher version
 % if that is not present, use (axis cs:4,14) instead of (4,14),
 % to specify that the values should be interpreted as axis coordinates
 \draw [dashed] (4,14) -- (25,2);
 

 
\nextgroupplot[title=Unsupervised learning]
\addplot [blue, only marks, mark=*, mark size=3] table [%
x = x, 
y = y, 
col sep = comma]{
    x, y
    %cluster 1
    2, 3
    3, 5
    4, 5
    3, 8
    5, 9
    3, 2
    5, 6
    6, 6
    7, 9
    10, 4
    11, 5
    9, 4
    };
    
\addplot+[red, only marks, mark=*, mark size=3] table [%
x = x, 
y = y, 
col sep = comma]{
    x, y
    20, 10
    21, 12
    24, 12
    25, 13
    27, 14
    22, 13
    23, 15
    25, 10
    15, 14
 };
 

 % save a coordinate for use later
 \coordinate (c2) at (23,12);
 
 % the blue circle is drawn inside the axis environment, and in axis coordinates
 % hence it becomes an ellipse
 \draw [blue, dashed] (6,6) circle[radius=5]; 

\end{groupplot}

% the red circle is drawn outside the axis, so actually looks like a circle,
% but the radius has no relation to the axis coordinates
\draw [red, dashed] (c2) circle[radius=1cm];


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hm, I sort of forgot having two axes .. Will edit.

Comment: This is great, thanks! How can I split the two graphics into two separate plots? - I will try this myself though. Additionally, how can I add black boarders around the circles? - Again I will also look into this. Thanks again!

Comment: @user113156 See updated answer for the first part, for the second `\addplot [draw=black, fill=blue,  ...`

Comment: This is great! I think this is better than what I had in mind. What I was originally thinking was to have two separate `tikzpicture` - one for supervised learning and another for unsupervised learning. I think I can figure this out though.